# Push Data to MongoDB on Google SignIn Firebase

Tags: node.js, mongodb, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

I wanted to write a method where onClick the google sign in starts and after successful sign in it makes a post request to my API.But the weird problem is **30% of the times** the sign in data doesnt come to mongo db.I even called signout function in the catch block.Please help if someone notice any error!!

```
    const Hero = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [fetchUser, setFetchUser] = useState(null);

  const handleGoogleSignIn = () => {
    const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider)
      .then(async (result) => {
         console.log(result);
        try {
          const { data } = await axios.post(
            "https://myAPIherokuapp.com/api/v1/9c142e80023e07c3/registerUser",
            { name: result.user.displayName, email: result.user.email }
          );
           console.log(data);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          signOut(auth)
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Also do you have a `onAuthStateChanged` observer initialized any where that perhaps is redirecting users before API request is sent
?

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes i have and also i never faced the error.But idk why myusers are facing this in some cases.I see them in firebase but not in mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try async/await at the `handleGoogleSignIn` level? e.g.

```
const handleGoogleSignIn = async () => {
  const googleProvider = await new GoogleAuthProvider();
  const userResult = await signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvier);
  await axios.post('url', userResult);
  ...
}
```

I think that should help?

Comment: 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.